# Loading assemblies as plugins

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, assemblies

I have a winforms project which allows future developers to create plugins for the appplication. The Winforms application contains all the interfaces and classes that the developer will need to reference when creating a plugin. Hence when I creat the plugin I reference the main application's dlls.

When the main application is initialized I create a seperate domain to load all the plugin dll's into. The reason I do this is so I can use the appDomain.unload call to remove plugins at will and then reload the remaining plugins.
When I start Debug in VS2008 my application initializes, it loads the first plugin but I get a warning that I need to load the plugin's referenced dlls that I use to reference the main application's interfaces.

**Now my question is prior to loading the dlls into the sub domain can I use the main application's interfaces in order to create an instance of them for the plugins to use as a reference? If yes, how can I do this? Any help is appreciated.**

this is the PluginManager of my application which loads the plugins found in the app.config file. I retained only the method that I need help on and the class's constructor.
In this class I'm reading an app.cinfig file and putting the contents of a customConfigSection into a customConfig collection. When loadAssemblies is called I loop through the collection and add the assemblies to the sub domain created in the constructor.

```
using System;
using MyApp.Data;
using MyApp.Interfaces;
using MyApp.Variables;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyApp.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This object helps the application manage its scalable and extended components
    /// called plugins.
    /// </summary>
    public class PlugInManager
    {
        public PlugInManager()
        {

            //appDomain setup
            pluginDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
            pluginDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = pluginDomainLocation;
            pluginDomainSetup.DisallowCodeDownload = true;
            string pluginApplicationName = string.Format(MAOIE.Variables.Constants.PLUGIN_APPLICATION_NAME);

            //appDomain creation
            pluginDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(pluginApplicationName, null, pluginDomainSetup);

            //Loads the values located in the config file
            LoadPluginConfiguration();
            //Load any existing plugins in the directories
            LoadAssemblies();
        }

        private void LoadAssemblies()
        {
            //I"m thinking I should add this the referenced libraries to the subdomain here.

            //AppDomain.Unload(this.pluginDomain);   
            string reference = GetReferencePath();
            reference += Variables.Constants.MAOIE_CORE_DLL;


            //Iterate through the items found in the app.config file.
            foreach (PluginSetting item in this.PluginConfigSettings.PluginItems)
            {
                string file = GetPluginPath();
                file += item.PluginFileName;

                switch (item.PluginType)
                {
                case Constants.PluginType.pluginTypeA:
                    pluginDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(file, item.PluginAssemblyType);

                    IPluginTypeA ia = (IPluginTypeA)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginDomain, item.PluginFileName, item.PluginAssemblyType);
                    Plugable<IPluginTypeA> pia = new Plugable<IPluginTypeA>();
                    pia.ConcreteClass = ia;
                    pia.Core = false;
                    //collection used throughout the application
                    this.aerodynamicAnalyzers.Add(pia);

                    return;
                case Constants.PluginType.pluginTypeB:
                    pluginDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(file, item.PluginAssemblyType);

                    IPluginTypeB ib = (IPluginTypeB)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginDomain, item.PluginFileName, item.PluginAssemblyType);
                    Plugable<IPluginTypeB> pib = new Plugable<IPluginTypeB>();
                    piB.ConcreteClass = ib;
                    pim.Core = false;
                    //collection used throughout the application
                    this.missionAnalyzers.Add(pib);
                    return;
                case Constants.PluginType.pluginTypeC:
                    pluginDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(file, item.PluginAssemblyType);

                    IPluginTypeC ic = (IPluginTypeC)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginDomain, item.PluginFileName, item.PluginAssemblyType);
                    Plugable<IPluginTypeC> pic = new Plugable<IPluginTypeC>();
                    pic.ConcreteClass = ic;
                    pic.Core = false;
                    //collection used throughout the application
                    this.pluginTypeCs.Add(pio);
                    return;
                case Constants.PluginType.pluginTypeD:
                    pluginDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(file, item.PluginAssemblyType);

                    IPluginTypeD id = (IPluginTypeD)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginDomain, item.PluginFileName, item.PluginAssemblyType);
                    Plugable<IPluginTypeD> piw = new Plugable<IPluginTypeD>();
                    pid.ConcreteClass = id;
                    pid.Core = false;
                    //collection used throughout the application
                    this.pluginTypeDs.Add(pid);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //end PlugInManager

}
//end namespace  MyApp.Core
```

This next class is a single class in a seperate project. I'm stubbing an empty plugin to test my pluginManager's LoadAssemblies method. I add a  references to the MyApp.Core.dll which is copied by visual studio into this project's bin directory. I need this in order to implement the interface found in the main application.

This class is just getters and setters plus an empty method.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  testPluginA.cs
// used as an empty class to test the import of plugins into the main application.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using MyApp.Core;

namespace testPluginA
{
    public class testPluginA : MyApp.Interfaces.IPluginTypeA
    {
        public testPluginA()
        { 

        }

        private string name = "testPluginA";
        private string desc = "Test Plugin A 1";
        /// <summary>
        /// The description of the plugin.
        /// </summary>
        public string Description { get{return this.desc;} }
        /// <summary>
        /// The display name of the plugin.
        /// </summary>
        public string FriendlyName { get{return this.name;} }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mp"></param>
        public void Optimize(MyApp.Data.Car car)
        { 
            //does nothing
        }
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is. Is it a problem when debugging in Visual Studio? Or is it a problem actually compiling the application? Or in running it?

Comment: The problem is running the application. When my first plugin loads I get a runtime error stating that my plugin is not loading MyApp.Core. The line of code where this fails is loading my assembly which uses MyApp.Core as a reference. That reference is made in the mock plugin project that I built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the plugins into the same domain, but make them implement an interface that exposes both a `Load` and `Unload` method. The public contract of the `Unload` method is [at least] the following:

- `Dispose()` where applicable and `null` all references to resources used by the plugin so the GC can collect them [at some point in the future]
- Remove its "connections" (whatever form they may be) into the main application so the main application's state is the same as before the plugin was loaded
- Place the plugin in a state where `Load` is a valid operation

It is the responsibility of your plugin writers to meet this contract. You are loading their code for execution anyway - if they break the rules things *will* go wrong whether or not you place them in their own AppDomain.

Edit: Personally, I think the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) is *at least* worth examining (and using if it meets your needs) as you build your API, though some here would disagree.

Comment: The reason I didn't place it in the same domain is because if the user wants to delete the file plugin the dll is released and removed. The only way I can achieve this is by using appDomain.Unload. Otherwise the dll will still be locked by the current session until the user exits the application. Will your recommendation meet this?

Comment: No, but you could make a copy of the assembly to a temporary cache of some sort and load it from there, where you clear the cache when the program exists. IMO, deleting a plugin while the program is running sure is a rare case to justify the performance degradation of cross-AppDomain plugin operations.